# How to get Client location using Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do you get Client location using Google Maps API v3? I tried the following code but kept getting the "google.loader.ClientLocation is null or not an object" error. Any ideas why ??

```
if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
            alert(google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude+" "+google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude);
        }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this :)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var loc = {};
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if(google.loader.ClientLocation) {
            loc.lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
            loc.lng = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng);
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    alert(results[0]['formatted_address']);
                };
            });
        }
    }

    google.load("maps", "3.x", {other_params: "sensor=false", callback:initialize});

    </script>
```

Comment: Using google.loader.ClientLocation is not a good idea, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195837/is-google-loader-clientlocation-still-supported

Answer (score 13):

A bit late but I got something similar that I'm busy building and here is the code to get current location - be sure to use local server to test.

Include relevant scripts from CDN:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
```

### HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

### JS

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

### DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/4ythpy02/

Comment: It is working fine but not accurate it has inaccuracy of approx 200 meteres How can we make it more accurate

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get the above code to work.

Google does a great explanation though here: 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation

Where they first use the W3C Geolocation method and then offer the Google.gears fallback method for older browsers.

The example is here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation.html

Answer (score 3):

No need to do your own implementation. I can recommend using `geolocationmarker` from [google-maps-utility-library-v3](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you now do not need to reverse geocode and now get the address directly from ClientLocation:

```
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city
```