# Get the location of Mobile User asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i am new in asp.net.
i am developing a website especially for mobile users.
i want to get the longitude and latitude by the client side, if mobile is support GPS so it enable the location by GPS on website.
how can i do that.
is this work on HTML5?

plz help
send some Code with description.

Thanks

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538211/ways-to-get-location-of-the-client-from-the-browser

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 Geolocation for this, it's not using the phones GPS though

http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/ for example.

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);

  function foundLocation(position)
  {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    alert('Found location: ' + lat + ', ' + long); //Do something
  }
  function noLocation()
 {
    alert('Could not find location');
 }
```

Comment: But remember that (most) browsers ask the user via a popup whether they will allow the access of `navigator.geolocation`.

Answer (score -1):

Use sim7100e attached to lattepanda with build in arduino the sim71000e will send a location data by sim7100e gps to the arduino this location data will process by arduino code then the arduino  send the data to c#  on lattepanda ang upload the data to your webpage by the internet

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is very broad. The question it is clear, even if not possible to reply in an easy way, but your answer... Please, try to edit it and describe it. If not, please delete it.

Comment: Please pay attention to questions ask