# How to set marker in google map using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using the below javascript code to show map and marker.The marker is loading while map load,but i want to load the marker if the button named "Add marker" is clicked.The marker should points to the current location.How to do this here.

js.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Marker',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
}; 
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

html

```
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please try this.  hope it help.
 1. make map as global variable.
 2. initialize map
 3. add marker on button click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
}; 

jQuery("$addmarker").click(function(){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.72, 72.100),
        title: 'Marker',
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
 })
</script>
```

Here is my complete sample code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initialize() 
{ 
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng('23.11', '71.00'),
    zoom: 2,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
 }

 function addMarker()
  {
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(23.72, 72.100),
                map: map,
            });
  }
 </script>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY onload="initialize();">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:700px; height:500px;"></div>
 <input type="button" id="addMarker" value="addMarker" onclick="addMarker();"/>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Comment: This map is loading,but onclicking add marker,marker is not comes to display

Comment: @MonkL, please set the position attribute as new google.maps.Latlng(latitude, longitude);
i have checked this code. it is adding Marker on button click in map.

Comment: Yes,i tested your code in separate html,it is working need one more help.Now the marker is set to some fixed lat and logitude,i need it to set at current place,can you tell me how to do.

Comment: @MonkL,i am so sorry. i have not ever tried for fetching current location.
but google map provides api for fetching current location. you can implement it by searching for google map.

Comment: @MonkL, you can get current location using answer of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780583/get-current-location-on-google-map

Answer (score 3):

`data` is `array` which contains lat and lng

```
   function addMarker(data) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
          map: map
        });
```

Comment: i updated these function "var marker = new google.maps.Marker" with you function,it is not working

Comment: If you want to have multiple markers..Use it recursively. For just one marker use it without function and place it after you define var map

Comment: I am getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined "

Comment: have you put your lat and lang in data array??

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the part:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   [...]
});
```

inside a `onclick` event listener.

The jQuery way to do this with a `button` element:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      [...]
   });
});
```

You have to think about making the variables `map` and `latLng` global.

Answer (score -1):

```
var map; // Declare map as global.

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
} 
// Call addMarker on click of the button.
function addMarker(){
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346); // Put lat long as desired.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Marker',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
}
```