# How can i get latitude and longitude coordinates from JSON Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api, google-maps

I know what i can get JSON LatLon (and other) data indicate my address in the URL

```
app.factory('myCoordinates', function myCoordinates($q, $http) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region')
            .success(function(coordinates) {
                var myCoordinates = {};
                myCoordinates.lat = coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                myCoordinates.lng = coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                myCoordinates.zoom = 14;
                deferred.resolve(myCoordinates);
        })

    return deferred.promise;

});
```

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=$region

But how can i get latitude and longitude coordinates of my current location without input my address in URL (automatically) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using html5 `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to get the latitude and longitude?

Example:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
  console.log(pos)
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's a really good way. But what do you think more accurately shows the location, Google API or HTML5 Geolocation? I would like as accurately as possible to show the user's location in the application

Comment: This is the link to the official documentation and looks like they're using navigator as well. soo..

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780583/get-current-location-on-google-map