# How to track device position using Google Map API's in Android

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am developing ionic App. My requirement is to track multiple device locations & show those location in google map.

Can anyone tell me how to track device position??

Is there any way to do this using google map API to track the device??

Anyone Help will be Appreciated!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Current Location On Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780583/get-current-location-on-google-map)

Comment: That question related to get current location. This is related to implement device tracking

Comment: You cannot track other devices inside an app without permission. And frankly, you shouldn't want to, since that's highly unethical.

Comment: you need to get some data like lat n lang from that devices through an Api call based on this u can u show them on map using markers.....you mentioned it as tracking so u need to make that api call for some time interval so that data will be updated and so that markers also updated

Comment: I am asking about mobile app

Comment: Is there is any other way to do this..like using device ID?

Comment: Is it possible to know device latitude and longitude values based on device ID from GPS?