# How to show search results of Google Maps embed at current location?

Tags: google-maps, iframe, embed

When I go to maps.google.com and search for, say, "restaurants", it will pinpoint all the locations that are markets in the maps. And I can press the embed and get an `iframe` code for embedding, like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m16!1m12!1m3!1d423284.5905135281!2d-118.41173249999996!3d34.020498900000014!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1srestaurants!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1423533559165" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

This just displays the map the same way when I was exporting it to be embedded. I want it to be able to get the user's current location and center it there and then show the nearby results for "restaurants". How can I do that?

P.S. I have taken a look at the [Embed API site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can try the following:

1.detect user device's location: [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940767/how-to-get-client-location-using-google-maps-api-v3/4919754#4919754)

2.search for near by places: [**Link**](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)