# Getting location in cordova-plugin-googlemaps for ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) in my ionic 1 project.
The problem is I can not get device location.
I am using the method provided by the plugin [getMyLocation()](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Location/README.md)

Here is my app.js code:

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
      var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
      var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);
      map.getMyLocation(function(location) {
      var msg = ["Current your location:\n",
      "latitude:" + location.latLng.lat,
      "longitude:" + location.latLng.lng,
      "speed:" + location.speed,
      "time:" + location.time,
      "bearing:" + location.bearing].join("\n");
      map.addMarker({
        'position': location.latLng,
        'title': msg
      }, function(marker) {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
      });
      });

  });
})
```

and this th body code in index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Map Project</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
      <div style="width:100%;height:500px;" id="map_canvas"></div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

All I get is a map, no markers pinned to my location

Can anyone see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option will be to use Cordova geolocation plugin. It will make your life a lot easier. else check this answer out [How to get Client location using Google Maps API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940767/how-to-get-client-location-using-google-maps-api-v3)